# How to collect a URL's facebook likes

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Using https://graph.facebook.com/id/likes?access_token=XXXXXXX works for some urls as does http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=url but some urls from locations like washingtonpost.com and techcrunch.com don't have the 'likes' data but it must be available because itstrending.com has these sites listed, with accurate likes counts.

Thanks

Comment: This is a run-on sentence. What's your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging around some more, I found this: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/links.getStats

Which gives you shares, likes and comments on a url.

Comment: is there a graph api equivalent?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this through [FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/):

```
SELECT like_count FROM link_stat WHERE url="http://www.washingtonpost.com"
```

returns 287.

Comment: Thanks. Any way you know of to do this with the graph api alone?